# How do I reorder rows in DataTable using drag drop?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces and JSF.  Can anyone tell me how do I reorder rows of a `DataTable` using Primefaces drag and drop component?

Comment: You will find solution here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940993/drag-and-drop-of-rows-primefaces-datatable-datagrid/21464068#21464068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently with in the PrimeFaces framework (v2.2.1 and 3.0) this is not possible with `<p:dataTable>`.

There is an open PrimeFaces [Issue 511 `<p:dataTable>` draggable columns](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=511) to add the Yahoo widget datatable draggableColumns attribute to the PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` but no target version is set yet.

If you would like to see this added to PrimeFaces star the issue to help give it higher priority.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking about re-ordering of rows, not columns? Why is this marked as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an older question, but the answer needs updating.  This is now doable using the `draggableColumns="true"` attribute on your `p:dataTable`.

Your `dataTable` would then look as such :

```
<p:dataTable var="i" value="#{bean.data}" draggableColumns="true">
```

#### Sources :

- PrimeFaces Showcase : [DataTable - Columns Reordering](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableReordering.jsf)

Comment: As @citress noted above, the OP seems to be referring to draggable rows, not columns.

Comment: @JacobAvlund Thanks for specifying. I've clearly missed this important piece of information.  I am not deleting my post at the moment, since the accepted answer remains on columns, and therefore this is updated.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available from PrimeFaces 5.0:

> Usage is very simple by just enabling draggableRows option and also an optional rowReorder ajax behavior is provided getting a ReorderEvent with index information for flexibility.

Source : http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3026

You can also have a look at the showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/reorder.xhtml